# Searching for multiple criteria in a joined table

Tags: sql

This seems like it would be simple but for some reason I can't get this to do what I want...

I have a recipe website and I want to be able to search recipes based on if whether they contain multiple ingredients. I have two tables one with all the recipe information and a second table with the ingredients. This is what I have so far but it does not retrieve any records. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT recipe.ID, recipe.Title, recipe.Photo FROM ingredient 
LEFT JOIN recipe ON ingredient.Recipe_ID = recipe.ID 
WHERE (ingredient.Description = 'egg' AND ingredient.Description = 'sugar' AND ingredient.Description = 'salt') 
GROUP BY recipe.ID
```

Comment: Google "relational division".

Answer (score 2):

If you want all recipes that have at least these 3 ingredients, then try:

```
SELECT recipe.ID, recipe.Title, recipe.Photo FROM recipe
WHERE recipe.ID in (
  SELECT Recipe_ID
  FROM ingredient 
  WHERE ingredient.Description in ('egg', 'sugar', 'salt')
  HAVING count(distinct ingredient.Description) = 3
  GROUP BY Recipe_ID
)
```

Comment: This worked out. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Jon: Great.  You can 'accept' this answer than by ticking the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting no results because the `AND` in your `WHERE` clause makes it an impossible condition, since you won't have one row where the description is all those values **simultaneously**.

Answer (score 0):

```
select recipe.ID, recipe.Title, recipe.Photo
from(
    select recipe.ID, recipe.Title, recipe.Photo
    ,count(ingredient.description) as num_ingredients 
    from ingredient left join recipe 
    on ingredient.recipe_id=recipe.ID
    group by 1,2,3
    )ingred_count
where num_ingredients>=2;
```

If you want to look at the recipes with multiple ingredients, that should do the trick.  Otherwise, if you want the number of ingredients for each recipe, take the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `ingredient` table contains `Recipe_ID`.  That will actually make this query pretty easy, since all you need to do is see which `Recipe_ID` are happening in more than one row.

```
SELECT I.recipe_id
FROM ingredient I
WHERE COUNT(I.description) > 0
GROUP BY I.recipe_id
```

will give the ID's for all such recipes.  if you want more than just the ID you'll need a join

```
SELECT R.*
FROM ingredient I
INNER JOIN recipe R on I.recipe_id = R.id
WHERE COUNT(I.description) > 0
GROUP BY I.recipe_id
```

I would strongly suggest you look into a many-to-many table which you would name something like `recipe_to_ingredient`.  That way you have a table `recipe`, a table `ingredient` and a table `recipe_to_ingredient` which will have recipe_id/ingredient_id pairs (and maybe amounts?)